# Autowiring Beans with Generic typed parameters at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, type-safety

Right, so I've been pulling my hairs on this for a while now and would love some suggestions.

I've got a class **Bar** with a **typed argument** that I need to wire.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class Bar<T> extends Foo<T> {

private final Utility utility;

public Bar<T> init(String a, int b) {
    //initializations
}

//some more methods

}
```

The way I see it, I can wire the class using `ApplicationContext` like so,

```
Foo<Detail> foo = applicationContext.getBean(Bar.class).init(a,b);
```

But this throws in a warning,

```
Type safety: The expression of type Bar needs unchecked conversion to conform to Foo<Detail>.
```

Now I understand this issue is because I've failed to mention the typed parameter  while initializing the bean of `Bar` class using `ApplicationContext`.

**`Question is, what might be the right syntax to mention the typed parameter <Detail> in the above statement?`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, I guess:

```
String [] names = context.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Bar.class, Detail.class));
Foo<Detail> bar = context.getBean(names[0]);
```

Comment: This too doesn't work mate. Seems I forgot to mention that `Detail` is not a spring managed bean but a regular old java bean class. Do you have any alternate workaround for in that case?

Comment: @AJC I see. The thing is you put (via `@Component`) into the spring context a bean that is generic `Bar<T>`. The only way to retrieve it would be via `context.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forClass(TestConfig.Bar.class))` or `context.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(TestConfig.Bar.class, Object.class));`. It is usually the other way around, you define a generic interface and add 2 or more generic Spring beans that implement that interface.

Comment: I hear you. Guess I need to redesign it a bit. Appreciate your suggestions.